# How to set the "sent event" when using picker view in storyboard?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uipickerview

I am studying the example of [date cell] (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008866-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). I added a pickerview in the storyboard, but   can't add events to the PickerView. In the example, there are a bunch of "sent events" shown in connections inspector, including value changed. But I can't find these options or drag events to ".m" file in my project. Could anyone has any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sent events are *actions*. To make one, there are a bunch of ways: simplest is this: first create an action handler in the view controller's class, then drag from the event in the connections inspector (or control-drag from the picker view) to the view controller in the storyboard.

Any simple tutorial on creating actions in a nib or storyboard will show you in detail. Here's the relevant section from my book:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_action_connections

You're in a storyboard, not a nib, so there's no File's Owner; instead, there's the owning View Controller. Everything else is exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, I tried this method to create an action in the view controller's class. But it can't be hooked to the picker view, while I can drag from the event to a button in the storyboard. Do I need to add delegate to the picker view? Thanks!

Comment: First create entire stub for `- (IBAction)dateAction:(id)sender { }` in MyTableViewController. Then you will be able to connect action event from picker to MyTableViewController.

Comment: It really will help if you read that chapter of my book first!